# How to select from an ltree with format n.n.n.n and sort as numbers at each level?

Tags: postgresql, ltree

The default sort on the ltree column is as text. Example: I have 3 columns in my table id, parentid and wbs. The ltree column - wbs has `1.1.12, 1.1.1, 1.1.2` stored in different rows. The select query ordered by wbs column returns `1.1.1, 1.1.12, 1.1.2.`

I need it to return `1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.12`

Comment: Please provide you tried queries, so community can help you, without trying you won't get much response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all elements of ltree values are integers you can transform them to integer arrays, which may be used to sort:

```
with my_table(wbs) as (
values 
    ('1.1.12'::ltree),
    ('1.1.1'),
    ('1.1.2')
)

select wbs
from my_table
order by string_to_array(wbs::text, '.')::int[]

  wbs   
--------
 1.1.1
 1.1.2
 1.1.12
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you. Does the LTREE provide any inbuilt feature to hold the sequence in which children of any node should be stored?

Comment: Ltree is based on *labels* which basically are just strings. It hasn't got any features to sort nodes on a path in another way than alphabetically. Maybe you should consider using integer arrays instead of ltree, of course in the case you don't use specialized ltree features like lqueries.